# Replace String in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I cannot figure out how to replace a string in a htaccess file. I need to change all of the urls on the site, currently they are formatted like this.

```
site.com/218-111-home/straight-black-mid-length-ladies-purse.jpg
```

and I need to redirect them to targets like this:

```
site.com/111-home/straight-black-mid-length-ladies-purse.jpg
```

I have tried for the life of me to get it to work, but I basically do not know how to take off the first three numbers after the domain and the -

Regex has beaten me.

Comment: What do you mean by "change the urls"? Do you want your users, when visiting the links like `218-111-home/` to be _redirected_ to `111-home/` changing their browser address, or just be sent internally and silently to content at `111-home/`?  If you mean to physically change the links in your content, Apache URL rewriting can't actually do that...

Comment: I am looking for it to redirect the first link to the second link. Sorry I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `RedirectMatch` rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9]+-([0-9]+-.+)$ /$1
```

Comment: That kills the existing images. The urls of the images have changed from the first url and now they are all like the second url. What I am trying to accomplish to redirect the first images to the new image path.

Comment: But this is what this rule is doing. It just strips `218-` from the from of URL.

Comment: Correct it does, but it also strips it out of the urls like this, site.com/111-home/straight-black-mid-length-ladies-purse.jpg which is the new url structure.